# Stripe Construct Event: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Javascript, Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments

I get an error whenever I try to construct the stripe webhook event:

> No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing

Cannot figure out how to solve this, already lot of json parsing methods but no one worked.

Here's my code:

```
app.post('/webhooks', express.raw({ type: 'application/json' }), (req, res) => {
    const signature = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
    console.log(signature);
    const endpointSecret = process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET;

    let event;

    try {
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.body, signature, endpointSecret);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
        console.log(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
        return;
    }

    switch (event.type) {
        case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
            const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
            console.log(paymentIntent);
            break;
        case 'payment_intent.payment_failed':
            console.log('Payment Failed');
    }

    res.status(200);

});
```

and these are my express uses:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.originalUrl === '/webhook') {
        next();
    } else {
        express.json()(req, res, next);
    }
});
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Comment: The `req.body` should be json string such as `{"id": "evt_test_webhook","object":"event"}`  try `console.log(req.body)` to make sure. Have you tried to test the signing https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#testing-webhook-signing with your enpointSecret?

Comment: ´´´const payload = req.body;
    const payloadString = JSON.stringify(payload, null, 2);
    const header = stripe.webhooks.generateTestHeaderString({
        payload: payloadString,
        secret: endpointSecret,
    })´´´ I still get the error

Comment: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/issues/356

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is *almost always* not using the RAW BODY in the `constructEvent`.  Stripe doesn't encode the "signature" in the JSON; they use "steganography" to encode the matching signature in the *non-coding* part of the JSON payload: extra spaces, line breaks, and other characters that are *ignored* by a JSON parser.  The resulting payload *can* be parsed as JSON for the webhook object, but the "signature" part needs the raw body *before* any parser has removed the *non-coding* steganography.

specifically:

```
event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.rawbody, signature, endpointSecret)
```

Comment: rawbody is undefined

Comment: if rawbody is undefined, either you have middleware modifying the payload, or you're using a different system.  Regardless, you need the *unmodified raw body of the request*, before any processing whatever.

You do *NOT* want to parse it as *anything* - it needs to be the body as sent by Stripe.